# Eclipse scout neon whole area around check box is clickable

Tags: user-interface, checkbox, eclipse-scout

I noticed that whole area around check box is clickable.

[image]

Is this a intentional functionality or a GUI bug? Problem is that user don't expect that if they click outside check box that value in chack box is changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is intended that the user may click on the label. But clicking on the white space right of the label should actually not change the value. We will look into this.

It is different for list boxes: Because list boxes support selection as well, we decided to make only the check box clickable instead of the whole row to prevent the user from accidentally change the checked state if he just wants to select / focus a row.